# Fgets rewriting last line on the position [0] of an string array on every call

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

i'm having a hard time finding the problem on an assignment for college. The program is a music player and it has like 5 functions which all work fine, but one, adding songs to the playlist. The problem is on the second call of the function, when it has to add a second song to the string array playList. I have noted debugging the code that in the moment I press enter after the fgets() function it changes playList[0] into what i just wrote, without even entering the function which modifies the array. So i think the problem comes from somewhere else than the function. I'd use a dynamic array, which would be a lot better but i'm not allowed to use dynamic memory D: (Sorry if i mispelled anything english is not my main language). I believe the problem is in the function fill_playlist, maybe when i assign a string to playList[i] but i can't find where. It also happens when i call fgets in the other menu option, Search Record.
I think it's a problem of pointer arithmetic i'm missing.
Basically everytime i use fgets() playList[0] is instantly filled with the last string written and i can't fill playList[1] or more.
Thanks
http://pastebin.com/FX2bHUSk

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIBRARY_DIRECTORY "/home/user/Desktop/library/" 
#define MSG_RANDOM_LIST "How many songs would you like to randomly listen?"
#define MSG_RANDOM_ERR "There are not that many songs in the list!"
#define MSG_INPUT_ERROR "There has been an input error!"
#define MSG_SEARCH "These are the songs in the playlist that contain the keyword: "
#define MSG_EMPTY_LIST "The list is empty! You can add records using the 'Add Record' function."
#define MSG_FULL_LIST "The list is full, you have added all the songs in the library!"
#define MSG_ALREADY_IN "The song you intend to add is already on the playlist. Please try with another one."
#define MSG_ADD_RECORD "Write the name of the song you would like to add."
#define MSG_WRONG_NAME "The song you entered is not in the list, please add another one."
#define MSG_SUCCESFUL_ADD "The song you wrote was succesfully added to the playlist!"
#define MSG_SEARCH_RECORD "Enter a keyword to search for a record on the playlist."
#define MSG_EMPTY_SEARCH "There are no songs matching the input keyword."
#define OPT_PLAY_IN_ORDER  "0 - Play in order."
#define OPT_PLAY_RANDOM "1 - Play randomly."
#define OPT_PLAY_RECORD "2 - Play record."
#define OPT_ADD_RECORD "3 - Add record."
#define OPT_SEARCH_RECORD "4 - Search record."
#define OPT_LIST_RECORD "5 - List records."
#define OPT_EXIT "6 - Exit."
#define MAX_PLAYLIST 25
#define MAX_RECORD 20
#define MAX_MENU 6

typedef enum {PLAY_IN_ORDER=0,PLAY_RANDOM=1,PLAY_RECORD=2, ADD_RECORD=3, SEARCH_RECORD=4,LIST_RECORD=5,EXIT=6} first_choice_t;
typedef enum {ST_INPUT_ERROR=0,ST_EMPTY_LIST=1,ST_FULL_PLAYLIST=2,ST_ALREADY_IN=3,ST_WRONG_NAME=4,ST_RANDOM_ERR=5,ST_EMPTY_SEARCH=6,ST_EXIT=7,OK=8} status_t;

void initialize_array(char ** array);
char * select_record (char ** playList, int i);
status_t menu_limit(int choice);
void printMenu();
status_t player(char ** playList);
status_t playOrder(char** playList);
status_t validateChoice(int choice, char ** playList);
status_t playRandom(int max_rand,char ** playList);
status_t printPlaylist(char** playList);
void playRecord (char * record);
int limit_random(int max_random);
void cleanstdin();
status_t add_record (char * record,char ** playList);
status_t fill_playlist (char * record,char ** playList);
status_t check_repeat (char * record,char ** playList,int length);
status_t search_record (char * keyword, char ** playList);

int main()
{
    /*string array which i'll initialize with 0s to fill with songs later.*/
    char * playList [MAX_PLAYLIST];
    status_t st= OK;

    initialize_array(playList);
    srand(time(NULL));
    if((st=player(playList))!=OK)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

/*prints the main menu of the program*/
void printMenu(){

    puts(OPT_PLAY_IN_ORDER);
    puts(OPT_PLAY_RANDOM);
    puts(OPT_PLAY_RECORD);
    puts(OPT_ADD_RECORD);
    puts(OPT_SEARCH_RECORD);
    puts(OPT_LIST_RECORD);
    puts(OPT_EXIT);

}

/*the program itself, depending on the input number continues with the selected function */
status_t player (char ** playList){
    int record_choice,max_random,choice;
    char aux[MAX_RECORD];
    char * record;
    char * keyword;
    char * err_library[] = {MSG_INPUT_ERROR, MSG_EMPTY_LIST, MSG_FULL_LIST,MSG_ALREADY_IN,MSG_WRONG_NAME,MSG_RANDOM_ERR,MSG_EMPTY_SEARCH};
    status_t st=OK;

    do{
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    cleanstdin();
    if((st =menu_limit(choice))!=OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",err_library[st]);
        return st;
    }


    switch(choice)
    {
        case(PLAY_IN_ORDER):
        {
            if((st=playOrder(playList))!=OK){
                fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", err_library[st]);
                }
            else 
                st = ST_EXIT;
            break;
        }
        case(PLAY_RANDOM):
        {
            puts(MSG_RANDOM_LIST);
            scanf("%d",&max_random);
            cleanstdin();

            if((st=playRandom(max_random,playList))!=OK){
                fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",err_library[st]); 
                break;
            }
            st=ST_EXIT;
            break;
        }
        case(PLAY_RECORD):
        {
            if((st=printPlaylist(playList))!=OK){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",err_library[st]);
                break;
            }
            scanf("%d",&record_choice);
            cleanstdin();
            if((st=validateChoice(record_choice,playList))!=OK){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err_library[st]);
                break; 
            }
            record = select_record(playList,record_choice);
            playRecord(record);

            st=ST_EXIT;
            break;
        }
        case(ADD_RECORD):{

            printf("%s \n",MSG_ADD_RECORD);
            fgets(aux,MAX_RECORD,stdin);
            aux[(strlen(aux)-1)]='\0';
            record= aux;
            if ((st=add_record(record,playList))!=OK)
                fprintf(stderr,"%s \n",err_library[st]);
            break;
        }
        case (SEARCH_RECORD):
            puts(MSG_SEARCH_RECORD);
            fgets(aux,MAX_RECORD,stdin);
            keyword= aux;
            if((st =search_record(keyword,playList))!=OK)
                fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",err_library[st]);
            break;

        case (LIST_RECORD):
            if((st=printPlaylist(playList))!=OK){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",err_library[st]);
                return st;
            }
            break;
        case(EXIT):
        {
            return ST_EXIT;
        }
        default:
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",MSG_INPUT_ERROR);
            return ST_EXIT;
        }
    }  
}while (st != ST_EXIT);
return OK;
}

/*Checks that, having six functions, you don't put a 7*/
status_t menu_limit (int choice){

    if (choice > MAX_MENU)
        return ST_INPUT_ERROR;
    return OK;
}

/*Plays the songs in the playlist in order*/
status_t playOrder(char ** playList){
    int i;
    char * record;

    for(i=0;playList[i] != 0 && i <MAX_PLAYLIST; i++){
        record = select_record(playList,i);
        playRecord(record);
    }
    if(i == 0)
        return ST_EMPTY_LIST;
    return OK;
}
 /*Checks that, having for example, 6 songs in the playlist, you don't put song n°7*/
status_t validateChoice(int choice,char ** playList){
    int i;

    for(i=0; playList[i] != 0 && i < MAX_PLAYLIST; i++);
    if(choice > MAX_PLAYLIST || choice > i)
        return ST_INPUT_ERROR;
    return OK;
}

/*Plays the playlist randomly */
status_t playRandom(int max_random,char ** playList){
    int i;
    status_t st;
    char * record;

    if ((st = validateChoice(max_random,playList)) != OK){
        return ST_RANDOM_ERR;
}
    for(i=0;i<max_random;i++){
    record = select_record(playList,limit_random(MAX_PLAYLIST));
    playRecord(record);
}

    return OK;
}
/*print current playlist*/
status_t printPlaylist(char ** playList){
    int i;

    for(i=0;playList[i] != 0 && i< MAX_PLAYLIST ;i++){
        printf("%d -%s \n",i,playList[i]);
}
    if (i == 0)
        return ST_EMPTY_LIST;
    return OK;
}

 /*recieves an int and returns the corresponding song (this could be all inside of playrecord)*/
char * select_record (char ** playList, int i){

return playList[i];
}
 /*given a string plays the record using mpg123 this function was provided by the one who thought the assignment*/
void playRecord (char * record){
    char * cmd[3];
    int pid = fork();

    cmd[0]="mpg123";
    cmd[1]=record;
    cmd[2]=NULL;
    if (!pid)
        execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
}

/*Initializes the array with 0s*/
void initialize_array(char ** playList){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_PLAYLIST;i++){
        playList[i]=0;
    }
}

int limit_random(int max_random){

    int number;

    number = (rand()%(max_random+1));

    return number;

}

void cleanstdin (void){

    int c;

    do
    {
        c=getchar();
    }
    while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}


 /*procedures and validations to add a song into the playlsit.*/
status_t add_record (char * record,char ** playList){
    status_t st;
    char aux[90];

    strcpy(aux,LIBRARY_DIRECTORY);
    strcat(aux,record);
    if (!access(aux, F_OK)){
        if((st=fill_playlist(record,playList))!=OK)
            return st;
    }
    else{
        return ST_WRONG_NAME;
    }
    return OK;

}

/* once the user inputs a name, and after making some validations adds the song to the playlist(first position that doesn't have a "0" on it)*/
status_t fill_playlist (char * record,char ** playList){
    int i;
    status_t st;
    char * aux;

    aux = record;
    for(i=0;playList[i] != 0 && i < MAX_PLAYLIST; i++){}
    if (i == MAX_PLAYLIST)
        return ST_FULL_PLAYLIST;
    if((st=check_repeat(aux,playList,i))!=OK)
        return st;

    playList[i]=aux;
    printf("%s\n",MSG_SUCCESFUL_ADD);
    return OK;
}
 /* Checks the songs which is about to be added isn't already in the playlist*/
status_t check_repeat (char * record,char ** playList,int length){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < length;i++){
        if(strcmp(record, playList[i])==0);
            return ST_ALREADY_IN;
    }
    return OK;
}

/*After receiving a keyword checks any match with all songs in the playlist*/

status_t search_record (char * keyword, char ** playList){
    int i,aux=0;


    for (i=0; playList[i] != 0 && i < MAX_PLAYLIST; i++){
        if(strstr(keyword, playList[i])!= NULL){
            printf("%s\n",playList[i]);
        aux++;
        }
    }
    if(i==0)
        return ST_EMPTY_LIST;
    if(aux == 0)
        return ST_EMPTY_SEARCH;
    printf("%s%s\n",MSG_SEARCH,keyword);
    return OK;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this function:

```
   status_t add_record (char * record,char ** playList){
    status_t st;
    char aux[90];

    strcpy(aux,LIBRARY_DIRECTORY);
    strcat(aux,record);
    if (!access(aux, F_OK)){
        if((st=fill_playlist(record,playList))!=OK)
            return st;
    }
    else{
        return ST_WRONG_NAME;
    }
    return OK;

}

/* once the user inputs a name, and after making some validations adds the song to the playlist(first position that doesn't have a "0" on it)*/
status_t fill_playlist (char * record,char ** playList){
    int i;
    status_t st;
    char * aux;

    aux = record;
    for(i=0;playList[i] != 0 && i < MAX_PLAYLIST; i++){}
    if (i == MAX_PLAYLIST)
        return ST_FULL_PLAYLIST;
    if((st=check_repeat(aux,playList,i))!=OK)
        return st;

    playList[i]=aux;
    printf("%s\n",MSG_SUCCESFUL_ADD);
    return OK;
}
 /* Checks the songs which is about to be added isn't already in the playlist*/
status_t check_repeat (char * record,char ** playList,int length){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < length;i++){
        if(strcmp(record, playList[i])==0);
            return ST_ALREADY_IN;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Paste the code here and rephrase the question to make it more readable

Comment: please, shorten your example to only include your problem

Answer (score 0):

`fill_playlist (song, list)` The problem in your call you will find if you look at the backtrace when reaching fill_playlist. The song you want to add into the playlist is not a uniqe pointer, but points to data stored on the stack. The quickest way fix this, is to do this inside full_playlist:

replace `playList[i]=aux;` with `playList[i]=strdup(aux);`.

I have not read the rest of the code for faults, but that was the most obvious fault I could find. (too free this string buffer again, send the pointer `strdup()` returned into `free()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've looked up and found this tip. But i'm using the ansi std and strdup is not included in it. Sadly compiling in this std is asked for the assignment.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use strdup(), make a functions that does the same, using `malloc(strlen(source)+1)` and `strcpy()`

Comment: I would but it is also a condition of the assignment not to use dynamic memory. It sucks, I know, must do things very inefficiently :/ . Anyway, you're saying the same pointer i'm using to the first song is the same i use for the second and so on? shouldn't this be solved if i use a local variable (inside fill playlist) to assign strings to playList[i]?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use dynamic memory, then the list has to be preallocated 2d array, and you have to copy in the data with `strcpy` in `fill_playlist()`  `char PlayList[EntriesCount][SongLength]`